# How can I fetch the number of pageviews per page on my site in the last 30 minutes with google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I would like to add a "what other people are doing" section to my react website, which shows the currently most interesting sections of my website using  google analytics. This means I would need fetch the most popular pages every 30 minutes from google analytics from within my pages backend, presumably using the realtime api, because I know that the reporting of the reporting API can be up to 24 hours out of date.
But unfortunately, the realtime API seams to only be able to track users that are using the page currently, and there doesn't seam to be a way to distinguish which actual page there on.
Basically what I need is a way to figure out how many individual people (not just people refreshing over and over again) have visited a certain section of my page in the last 30 minutes. Google analytics seams to be the way to go but I'm open to any other solution, as long as it can be used from within the aws cloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to remember is that the Google Analytics website also uses the Google Analytics API.  If something you want to see can be done on the website for the most part you can also do it with the api, with the exception of a few of the calculated metrics which can be a bit tricky to duplicate with the API.

The reporting of the Google analytics Reporting API takes between 24 - 48 hours to process your data until that time your data will not be completed processing so the numbers will not be correct.

The google analytics real-time api would be an option but the data is limited into how long it stays around as well is what dimensions and metrics you can actually view as they are only giving you access to what they are sure has completed processing.

An issue with both of these solutions would be the quota, every view on google analytics is only allowed to make **10k** requests per day.  You will need to ensure that you stay within this so if you are only requesting data every thirty minutes around the clock you should be able to keep this to around 48 calls but its wroth noteing.

IMO Google analytics is not suited for this task you should keep a running count on your own website store it in the database and use that.

Comment: Yeah, that would be the plan, have a lambda script run every half hour, collect the current data from GA and store it in my database. I did some digging in the meantime, and it seams that the "rt:pageviews" metric counts the pageviews that happened in the last 30 minutes, which would be exactly what I need. If you say I can only fetch 10 requests per day from GA, does this mean I can't send 48 requests (per page) to GA? Also by "keep a running count", do you mean fetch the count from GA and store it, or create my own analytics solution?

Comment: Im very sorry about my type-o there.  Its 10k requests a day per view as in 10,000 but this is across all apps.  My note on this was mainly so that you dot set it to run every time a user hits your page as you will run out of quota it would need to be set into a job.